# Sorting algorithm speeds

Tags: sorting

I have made a sorting algorithm that works like no other I know of, and I would like to have it tested. Did anyone come across a site where you can compare how your algorithm stands beside already known ones?

So bunch of data and end-cases are needed to be thrown at it with time results.

Comment: Probably codereview site is better for such questions

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. You may want to post your algorithm to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you've got a C or C++ implementation, I can compare it to algorithms I have with a few benchmarks, but I don't know of any specific resource.

Comment: On the other hand, if you simply describe the algorithm, we might also be able to tell you that it already corresponds to some extent to a lesser-known sorting algorithm.

Comment: You could download source code for various common algorithms, and compare them to yours. In my case, I was only interested in how the sorts handled pseudo random data. In my testing in X86 64 bit mode where there are 16 working registers, sorting a large (4 to 16 million) array of 64 bit integers, I found that a 4 way bottom up merge sort was about as fast as quicksort (about 15% faster than 2 way bottom up merge sort). You could compare your algorithm to quicksort or mergesort on random data to get an idea of relative performance.